# Wicket AjaxEventBehavior with History API

Tags: java, ajax, wicket, html5-history, wicket-7

I am using Wicket 7.x with the History API. I am currently trying to wire up an AjaxEventBehavior for "onpopstate". I have code that adds an object whenever I do history.pushState, my problem is I can't access this extra information from the Java side with onEvent.

Sample pushState:

```
target.appendJavaScript("history.pushState({query: '" + 
searchResults.getQueryString() + "'}, null, window.location.pathname);");
```

EventBehavior:

```
this.getPage().add(new AjaxEventBehavior("onpopstate")
{     
     @Override
     protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target)
     {
         //code to get query defined in pushState
     }
});
```

updateAjaxAttributes is not a solution because it is only called when the page is rendered. I need to send this extra data when popstate is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updateAjaxAttributes can actually help you. AjaxRequestAttributes lets you specify also dynamic extra attributes (see [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Wicket+Ajax) for more info). These parameters are dynamically calculated on client side before AjaxEventBehavior is triggered and are sent as request parameters.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the tip. It has put me on the right track! I'm now using getDynamicExtraParameters as you suggested. The only issue I'm facing is when the extra parameters are added, it's happening too early in my event to retrieve the correct information. Is there any way to delay the execution until a later time? The current value I'm passing to getDynamicExtraParameters is "return {'query' : attrs.event.originalEvent.state.query}".

Comment: I've found a solution to my problem, I was misusing the History API. Thank you for the great answer!